# How can I generate list of tailwindcss class name used in a project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, tailwind-css, postcss

Tailwindcss works by scanning all file that the location are specified in `content` in tailwind.config.js. When the build action run, tailwindcss will generate css file containing the preflight and the classes used in the project. My question is, can How can i get the list of class names, including custom class (like p-[60px]), that used in my entire project?

i expect to get at least log of class names used in my project, but a file containing list of the class names is better.

Comment: You just need a txt file containing all the class names? just the names? not the implementation+?

Comment: yes. txt contains the class name only. So, I have a remote component that I can import in my micro frontend setup. but, since the component is remote, my local tailwind cant scan that. my idea is I want to extract the CSS used in my remote component library, put the extracted class name used, and use it to be scanned (include the file to the content config), so in my local, I will have all the class name generated

Comment: Are you sure this is a standard or a practical way for solving this?

Comment: i dont know, yet. You can suggest a better approach